# Uncaught ReferenceError: pathname is not defined

Tags: javascript

buenas estoy practicando Javascript junto a laravel y estoy trayendo por medio de una promesa datos para mostrarlos por medio de un select.

le paso por medio del fetch la ruta, todo funciona bien, pero le tengo la ruta "quemada en codigo", ahora, si por ejemplo yo subiera eso a un servidor o lo moviera etc tendría que estar cambiando esa ruta a cada archivo que tenga una promesa.. por lo que quiero capturar la ruta absoluta y pasarlo por medio de un parámetro.

Lo estoy tratando de hacer de esta manera pero me da error

```
$(document).ready(function () {

const $especie = document.getElementById('id_especie')
const $raza    = document.getElementById('id_especie_raza')

function getAbsolutePath() {
  var loc = window.location;
  var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(0, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  return loc.href.substring(0, loc.href.length - ((loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).length - pathName.length));
}

const $url    = getAbsolutePath();

$especie.addEventListener('change', () => {
  
  $raza.options.length = 0;
  console.log(pathname);
  options = document.createElement('option')
  options.value = 0
  options.text  = 'Seleccione Raza'
  $raza.add(options)
  
  fetch( `${$url.value}/raza/${$especie.value}`) //ACA TENGO EL PROBLEMA
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
         data.forEach(data => {
           options = document.createElement('option')

           options.value = data.id
           options.text  = data.nombre_raza

           $raza.add(options)
         });
     })
  })
```

});

el error que me muestra es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría hacer para que en el fetch reciba el parámetro de la URL

Comment: Y si nos ayudas indicando exactamente donde te lanza el error?

Comment: Tu variable `pathName` sólo existe dentro de la función `getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: @Einer En el momento que hago la selección de especie debe mostrar los datos de la raza.. lo que sucede, es que al tratar de pasar la ruta absoluta por medio del parametro `$url` me da error, pero, si quemo la ruta en código si funciona la promesa osea si pongo en el fetch `http://sisvet.test/mascota/raza/${$especie.value}` si funciona.. lo que pienso es que no es practico tener la URL quemada en código

Comment: Te recomiendo que ese console.log() sea de $url, no de pathname, ya que como te dijo el compañero @MauricioContreras, pathname solo existe DENTRO de la función getAbsolutePath(). A partír de ahí podrás indicarnos qué devuelve esa variable para poder seguir ayudándote :)

Comment: Gracias Mauricio y Benito efectivamente fue error mio en el console.log. Al ponerlo correctamente vi que se imprimía dos veces al final // solo quite la variable pathname y funciono correctamente